# How to jump to a particular row in MySQL using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am using a query which is returning around 5000 rows in all.

I want to give facility to user to jump to any particular record by entering the record number.

so for example if the user enters 10 I want to jump to record #10 and retrieve its values.

Using mysql_fetch_assoc is a painful and very slow.

How can I do this easily and quickly?

TIA

Yogi Yang

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no concept of record "#10" in MySQL, or really in most databases, as records have no internal ordering, and are modeled as sets.  That being said, if you want to return a result a record offset by a certain amount, you could use `LIMIT` with `OFFSET`:

```
SELECT col
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY someCol    -- use this to order if you want
LIMIT 1             -- return a single record of interest
OFFSET 9            -- start at record #10
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But then this means I will have to keep on firing an SQL Query every time a user needs to jump to a particular row. WIll this not tax MySQL and the web host?

Comment: @YogiYang007 In general, you will need to hit the database each time the user interacts with the data anyway, e.g. when paging, searching, expanding, etc.  So using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` doesn't necessarily change this as far as I know.